# go.GetComponent<x> ()

Tags: components, unity-game-engine

*Hi
im trying to use multiple type of component in my unity script that user selects that:*

```
public enum UI_Type{
    Button,InputField,Dropdown,Slider,Toggle
}

public UI_Type UIType;
```

I want do this action:

```
Component c=go.GetComponent<UIType.Button> ();
```

But I cant use this.
I tried this method:

```
Component UIComponent(GameObject go,UI_Type ui){
    switch (ui) {
    case UI_Type.Button:
        return go.GetComponent<Button> ();
        break;

    case UI_Type.Dropdown:
        return go.GetComponent<Dropdown> ();
        break;

    case UI_Type.InputField:
        return go.GetComponent<InputField> ();
        break;

    case UI_Type.Slider:
        return go.GetComponent<Slider> ();
        break;

    case UI_Type.Toggle:
        return go.GetComponent<Toggle> ();
        break;

    default:
        return null;
        break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I used this function below :

```
UIComponent(go,UIType).OnPointerEnter (new PointerEventData (EventSystem.current));
```

but this has became RED

Comment: What do you mean by "this has became RED" ? What error do you have in your console ?

Comment: unity monodeveloper coloring "OnPoinerEnter" sentece because the command is not correct.I wrote above commands that explain what i want to do: "Using One script for all type of toggle , button , slider and other ui clickable items". but i cant found any way